# Перекус и безвиз

Tags: словообразование, синонимы

Трудно определиться, какое слово хуже. *Безвиз* похож на «засланного казачка», и от этого как-то немного легче. Но другой-то уродец  — здешний на все сто. Раньше (и по Ефремовой) он значил изъян в прикусе у собак. Как же объяснить его появление при наличии *закусывания*, *полдника*, *второго* или *лёгкого завтрака*?

Answer (score 3):

Скажу сразу, не то ни другое мне слух особо не режет, хотя, конечно, нормативность пока на уровне разговорности, не выше.

Объяснить можно тем, что "перекус" не привязывается к какому-то конкретному времени или событию (в строгом ряду последовательности приема пищи), т. е. в известном смысле объединяет все названные понятия. Что касается всяких ланчей и полдников, то они четко привязаны к обеду (хотя исторически полдник был приемом пищи в полдень, перед обедом). При этом, кстати, не возникает проблем перевода, в большинстве стран Европы "обед", который dinner, по времени (но не по обилию) соответствует нашему ужину, а обед, который ланч - это действительно второй завтрак. Поэтому универсальное "перекус" вполне к месту. Другое дело, что волею некоторых менеджеров отелей и т. п. этот перекус пытаются привязать к какому-то определенному приему пищи (обычно - полднику), вот это порождает вопросы.

Вот читаю рекомендации по правильному питанию при некотором заболевании. Простите, но тут дневной рацион разбит на семь крошечных приемов пищи. И два "перекуса", перед ланчем-обедом и после основного обеда тут очень даже удобны как термины.

Что касается безвиза, то тут обсуждать особо нечего, ну вот так сложилось. вряд ли только стоит относить его к заимствованиям, разве что некая калька, но скорее всего именно на русской (восточнославянской) почве и образовалось. А почему нет?

Answer (score 0):

Говоря о «почве» *безвиза*, следует учитывать, что французский корень из-за смешения с нижегородской составляющей сопротивляется склонению, и вариант *безвизо* на итальянский манер (***авизо***) был бы куда логичней и приятнее слуху, несклоняемое и с ударением в конце. Ну, а пока, уверен, если дать сейчас эту тему в формате «Найди лишнее слово», то его без труда каждый отыщет: каприз, эскиз, маркиз, архыз, карниз, безвиз, парадиз, приз, вокализ.

Что касается *перекуса*. Процесс по определению вредного питания на ногах — на бегу, без должных условий — выбрал себе жертву, приватизировал существующее слово, которое перекрасил и перевёл в разряд положительных (перекус стал полезен: рецептами правильных перекусов переполнена сеть).

Развитие темы начального *перехватить кус* (у М. Булгакова) диминутивом, или ещё проще — сменой рода — *торопливая **перекуска*** (у Ф. Гладкова), дало бы совсем не худший результат.